# Displaying title on FontAwesome icon in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, font-awesome, title

I have a FontAwesome icon in my data table with a title. The title displays fine in Chrome but not in IE. I searched for the issue but did not find anything useful.

To test it, I copied the icon out of the data table and pasted it outside, somewhere on the page. I get the same result (I thought it might have something to do with jQuery data table).

This is what is on the HTML page:

```
<i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true' title='Edit ABCDE'></i>
```

This is what gets rendered (I truncated most of SVG code):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" title="Edit ABCDE" class="svg-inline--fa fa-edit fa-w-18" role="img" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-Tck9jWzzHTo4" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-icon="edit" data-fa-i2svg="" data-prefix="fa">
<title id="svg-inline--fa-title-Tck9jWzzHTo4">Edit ABCDE</title>
<path fill="currentColor" d="M 402.6 83.2 l 90.2 90.2 ..." />
</svg>
```

Comment: You said 'title', do you mean when we hover the icon it shows the tooltip or any text that gets displayed along with the icon? I test the sample code and I found that it is displaying the icon and tooltip properly in the IE 11 browser. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/RVLyZbN) I am not sure why it generates the SVG on your side. On my side, HTML code remains the same when I check it using developer tools. Further, you can check in the IE browser settings that the 'Font download' option is enabled for the relevant zone. Let me know if I am misunderstanding anything I will try to correct myself.

Comment: When I hover over the icon it shows nothing; nothing displayed in console so I can say there is no js error. I tested in IE and Chrome; works fine in Chrome but not in IE. Both browsers show SVG for me when I inspect the element. Font Download option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see what the problem was with title not showing up when it was associated with a FontAwesome icon in IE but working fine in Chrome. I event entertained using Bootstrap/jQuery tooltip.

But I moved the title from the icon to its associated anchor and it solved the issue.

I changed:

```
<a href='...' ...><i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true' title='Edit ABCDE'></i></a>
```

to:

```
<a href='...' title='Edit ABCDE' ...><i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
```

I still would really like to know why IE chokes on displaying title in a FontAwesome icon.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.